# How to import .csv files into SAP HANA Trial account

Tags: java, csv, hana

I'm trying to import .csv files into SAP HANA database to get data after with Java, does anybody know how can I do that?

The most important is to add the .csv file to the database, search for the data I have more time to research.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you trying to programatically load CSV files into HANA using Java OR Trying to load CSV files into HANA, for which you plan to writing a Java application to view/manipulate the data?

Comment: thats correct, e need that the data of my csv be on the hana, and then i'll manipulate.

Comment: he generate an servelet aumatic with this function

                             

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
   throws ServletException, IOException {
  doGet(req, resp);
 }

Comment: but i don't know how to use it

Comment: If you are using hana java application which is non-native, you can load the csv using java file reader and then insert the data using database connectors.

Comment: I have already made the program that reads the csv file, but how can i connect into the database? i'm looking for a long time and can't find how i connect to the database,

Comment: Hi Anderson!
Did you find someway to connect to hana in java program ?

Comment: Use the HANA JDBC driver - see http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/ff/15928cf5594d78b841fbbe649f04b4/frameset.htm and https://scn.sap.com/thread/3217656

Answer (score 0):

If it is not too much data you can use HANA Studio to import your data from CSV files. Therefore:

1. Start HANA Studio
2. Login into your trail account from HANA Studio
3. Select `Import ...` from the `File` menu
4. Select `Data from Local File`
5. Select the system to where you want to import to
6. Go wild on the options :-)